# Modifying and saving plist in iPhone app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an iPhone app where I have to modify the plist at runtime. I am successfully able to do  it on simulator but when I run it on device it retrieves the data from the old plist and modification is not done. This is the code I am using for getting the path of the plist -

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Customer.plist"];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path])
{
    path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Customer" ofType:@"plist"];
}



NSMutableDictionary *mainDictionary;
mainDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];
```

Answer (score 0):

To write a dictionary on plist file this line may work

```
[dicionaryToWrite writeToFile:path atomically: TRUE];
```

Comment: Thanks but I am already using this line of code. I feel the problem is related to path of the plist.The code that I shared is for getting the path of plist file only. It works on simulator but not on device.